# How to access the contents of a div with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have Beautifulsoup up and running, however when parsing the html for the website I'm targeting the "soup" object doesnt seem to show the divs within divs and so forth. Im trying to get item details from a website that is many layers deep. When viewing the actual site html I can see what layer I'd like to get to, but the soup only shows the parent div, which looks like the following:

```
<div id="react-views-container"></div>
```

how do I get inside this div?

my code looks like the following so far:

```
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#setting up connection and testing by printig html
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler("proxies_hidden_for_privacy")
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
html = urllib.request.urlopen("target_website").read()
print (html)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

div = soup.find(id="react-views-container")
```

Comment: Can you share the website you are trying to scrap and the `div` tag you are looking in it. ?

Comment: yeah I am going to do this multiple times over but the website is instacart.com. I'm trying to see what items are returned by certain search terms. a specific example is this search for cherries     https://www.instacart.com/store/the-fresh-market/search_v3/cherry    the div i mention "react-views-container" seems to hold the grid of returned items. I'd like to get the name of the items returned which seem to be in <div class="item-card-contents" data-radium="true"> which is within

Comment: Okay. I am checking it out. Will back to you soon

Comment: mitch: please move those question details into the question body, not a comment. Comments aren't indexed or searchable, they're ephemeral and likely to get deleted eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly pass the `div` id you want in the code below ;

```
soup.find("div", {"id": "id-you-want"})
```

This works well when you want `div` inside `div`

**Or**

You can even use this,

```
soup.find_all('div')
```

It will give you all a list of all the `div`. Then you can filter out the `div` you want.

Edit ::

on analyzing the website we can see that it is loading up the elements (the Items) dynamically and possibly it is doing so with javascript and Some XHR request.

**Solution**

This problem can be solved if you use `scrapy` or `selenium` since they use a web driver so it would be easy to **scrape** such websites using them instead of `BeautifulSoup`.

The next possible approach could be that you find the URLs ( XHR / API ) that the website is calling for fetching the items.

Note: I am updating the URL's soon

Edit 2:

**Request**

```
https://www.instacart.com/v3/containers/sprouts/search_v3/milk?source=web&cache_key=38e8f7-7370-t-35b&per=50&tracking.items_per_row=5&tracking.source_url=undefined&tracking.autocomplete_prefix=&tracking.autocomplete_term_impression_id=&tracking.search_bar_impression_event_id=
```

This is giving `response` containing items in `json` format. You can **scrape** your items from this.

**Can't add response since it's large in size and my Google chrome tab starts to hang LOL. But I have verified**

Comment: I have seen this before and it gives me the same answer as my current code. I might not be clear but I don't know how to access the contents of the div. there is alot going on inside of    <div id="react-views-container"></div>    but it is not even showing up in the soup. when I try to search for div id's, that I can visually see within, it returns a None object

Comment: Are the `div` tags inside getting loaded dynamically? I guess that's because it's not showing and returning None

Comment: It would be helpful to answer  if you can share the website and the `div` id you are looking for /

Comment: More than likely (judging by the `id` name) this is a `single page application` which works off Javascript and normally requesting some kind of API / backend to grab the content, etc.. Share the website if you can and look at all requests happening when the page loads.

Comment: yeah it is starting to seem that way @antfuentes87, I'm not really familiar with web apps so this is new to me. I discuss the website and example in the comments under the initial question, thanks

Comment: @mitch I Have edited my previous answer. You can check it out. Hope this solves your problem

Comment: @antfuentes87 Share your views on the updated answer. :)

Comment: @0xPrateek Exactly what I would have done (great job!). The `json` response is very easy to work with and then you don't have to mess with any `HTML` (which is always nice). And another +1 for not using `selenium`!

Comment: @0xPrateek absolutely, I am just working with it now to understand it a little better, currently using scrapy. And just to make sure I understand, I need to use a web driver because this style of web app is dynamic and is filling in the pieces i want to scrape on demand?

Comment: You can use the second approach I have discussed that is of getting the item details using URL. You can create a custom URL as per your query. and get's response in json which is way easy to parse.

Comment: @0xPrateek You may just want to give a full example, so he understands that this is just a request to that API end point (not loading the entire web page).

Comment: @barny Thanks for correcting ..! I didn't notice that. :)